# Can I make my ebook free while retaining the paperback available on KDP

Tags: kdp

I have a computer title as an ebook and a paperback on KDP. Because the book is about an open-source software I have promised to make the ebook free after one year. I can make the epub a free download from my website. My question is whether KDP will allow the ebook to be removed while continuing to sell the paperback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paperback and ebook are two different items, as far as KDP is concerned. I have published some paper book without the Kindle version (which is free on my site) and nobody ever complained.

Comment: Has Amazon spelled out the policy anywhere? Many years ago, Amazon manually checked that one of my ebooks was available on some pirate sites and refused to list it. I do not remember if it was ebook or paperback. I think at that time they had only ebooks in self-publishing option.

Comment: I never published my ebooks on Amazon (I am not sure if it is possible to set their price at 0), so I am not sure about it. But I do know that they were pressing me to publish also the Kindle version ("Hey! Just give us the manuscript and we automatically convert in azw3 format!") and I did not, so I think having only the paper versions is ok for them. After all, they are print-on-demand so they don't have to stock them.